# Python, two strings should return three parameters

Tags: python, string

I need some help with this problem:

Create a Python function that receives two strings as parameters. The function should return three elements:
A set containing the words that are present in both data structures;
A set containing the unique words present in the text;
A set containing the words that are only present in the second data structure.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: use set() with list iterations.

Comment: Please, at least try to solve your problem, and then come back with specific problem. [How much effort is expected on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Matthias for his comment. First split the text into words and then you can use standard methods for sets like intersection for the first question, symmetric difference for the second question and the difference for the third question.

```
def f(text1: str, text2: str):
    words1 = set(text1.split())
    words2 = set(text2.split())

    result1 = words1.intersection(words2)
    result2 = words1.symmetric_difference(words2)
    result3 = words2.difference(words1)

    return (result1, result2, result3)
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please avoid posting code-only answers. Please add some explanation to it and describe the important parts, what the do and why you did it that way.
Also, please notice that this question has the characteristics of "posted homework". It's not only good manners, but a requirement to post, what has been tried so far and to give code snippets.

Comment: I think it's a typo, it should say "the texts". So all the unique words that only appears one time in either text :) Do you know how I should write that as well?

Comment: You might want to have a look at some methods of a `set`, like [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) and [`difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference).

Comment: @Matthias I didn't know that they were standard methods of sets, I'll look into it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm very new at programming, and think it's really hard, but I will try to show some of my own work and thoughts in the future.